# How to create a variable identifying unique groups based on series of values of another variable?

Tags: r

I have a dataset df with two variables : one (ascendantly ordered) posixct variable date.time and one numeric variable value. The variable value consists of a series zeros or a series of different positive numbers greaer than zero. The length of each serie is random but greater than one.

**Edit: loading the lubridate library**

```
library(lubridate)
```

**The dataset df:**

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(date.time=seq(ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00"),ymd_hms("2016-01-01 01:00:00"),length.out = 20),value=c(runif(3,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(5,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(4,1,3)))
```

**The desired outcome:**

```
desired.outcome <- cbind(df,peak=c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,3))
```

I would like to create a third variable called peak that identifies each series of positive numbers greater than zero as a *separate* "peak". A peak is defined as a series of positive numbers greater than zero that are between two series of zeros.

- What would be an efficient way to obtain the desired outcome for df > 5 million rows, preferably using data.table or Dplyr?

Comment: Error in seq(ymd_hms("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), ymd_hms("2016-01-01 01:00:00"),  : 
  could not find function "ymd_hms"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option (in `mtd2`) for your consideration:

```
set.seed(10L)

#generate dataset of 5million rows as OP mentioned
N <- 5e6
df <- data.frame(value=10*runif(N))
#randomly set 25% of values to 0
df[sample(N, 0.25*N), "value"] <- 0

##original dataset of 20 rows
# df <- data.frame(date.time=seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 01:00:00"),length.out = 20),
#     value=c(runif(3,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(5,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(4,1,3)))

mtd1 <- function() {
    inverse.rle(with(a<-rle(df$value>0), modifyList(a, list(values=cumsum(values)*values))))   
}

val <- df$value
mtd3 <- function() {
    result <- rleidv(val>0)
    result[!(val>0)]<-0
    result[val>0]<-rleidv(result[val>0])   
}

library(data.table)
mtd2 <- function() {
    setDT(df)[, peak := (value > 0) * ceiling(rleid(value > 0) / 2)]
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd1(), mtd3(), mtd2(), times=5L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
 mtd1() 357.755701 375.957301 517.6211210 610.545700 611.407001 632.439902     5
 mtd3() 312.756201 329.190100 385.4440206 329.810201 352.368101 603.095500     5
 mtd2() 181.146901 187.001001 256.8531808 215.238501 221.030000 479.849501     5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a=rle(df$value>0)
a$values=cumsum(a$values)*a$values
peak=inverse.rle(a)
peak
[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3


cbind(df,peak)
             date.time    value peak
1  2016-01-01 00:00:00 2.014956    1
2  2016-01-01 00:03:09 1.613537    1
3  2016-01-01 00:06:18 1.853815    1
4  2016-01-01 00:09:28 0.000000    0
5  2016-01-01 00:12:37 0.000000    0
6  2016-01-01 00:15:47 0.000000    0
7  2016-01-01 00:18:56 0.000000    0
8  2016-01-01 00:22:06 2.386204    2
9  2016-01-01 00:25:15 1.170272    2
10 2016-01-01 00:28:25 1.450873    2
11 2016-01-01 00:31:34 1.549061    2
12 2016-01-01 00:34:44 1.544610    2
13 2016-01-01 00:37:53 0.000000    0
14 2016-01-01 00:41:03 0.000000    0
15 2016-01-01 00:44:12 0.000000    0
16 2016-01-01 00:47:22 0.000000    0
17 2016-01-01 00:50:31 2.231659    3
18 2016-01-01 00:53:41 1.859343    3
19 2016-01-01 00:56:50 2.303311    3
20 2016-01-01 01:00:00 2.135476    3
```

Doing this in a single line:

```
inverse.rle(with(a<-rle(df$value>0),modifyList(a,list(values=cumsum(values)*values))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not a beauty:

(can't eval your data)

```
set.seed(10)
value=c(runif(3,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(5,1,3),rep.int(0,4),runif(4,1,3))
```

code:

```
library(data.table)

result <- rleidv(value>0)
result[!(value>0)]<-0
result[value>0]<-rleidv(result[value>0])
```

result:

```
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3
```